# sigma.js / Spring Data Rest / Neo4j - right design?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-rest, sigma.js

I am building a java/javascript application in order to extract data from Neo4j and visualize it.

I have chosen to use spring data / spring data rest in order to interact the graph through rest API and it is working fine.

In order to implement the visualization I tried sigma.js. The JSON format expected by sigma.js is not the same as the one exposed by spring data rest. To move forward I would like to implement a custom controller (using spring MVC) with the appropriate JSON transformation.

My objective is to be able to provide an entry point (e.g. one Node) through the UI and after being able to interact dynamically with the graph.

Do you think it is the right design? Any suggestion?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a custom rest controller for the JSON format you expect would make sense,

see our example here (it is for d3 but you get the idea):

http://neo4j.com/developer/java/#_using_spring_data_neo4j

There is also a linked github repository with the code.